# Spring batch MongoItemReader to read as json

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to write a Spring Batch job that reads documents from a mongo db and writes the documents to a CMS (for now I will attempt to test this first with WireMock). Can I set up the job and itemreader without specifying the exact structure of the document? I would just like to read each document as json and then sent that json through to the CMS. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSON is just a String, you should configure your `MongoItemReader`  for `String` type and provide `MongoTemplate` with some custom simple converter:

```
public class DBObjectToStringConverter implements Converter<DBObject, String> {
  public String convert(DBObject source) {
    return source == null ? null : source.toString();
  }
}
```

This one just return a String JSON representation of `DBObject`.

Then configuration:

```
<mongo:db-factory/>

<mongo:mapping-converter id="mappingConverter">
    <mongo:custom-converters>
        <mongo:converter>
            <bean class="com.my.batch.mongo.DBObjectToStringConverter "/>
        </mongo:converter>
    </mongo:custom-converters>
</mongo:mapping-converter>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="mappingConverter"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader">
    <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate"/>
    <property name="query" value="..."/>
    <property name="targetType" value="java.lang.String"/>
</bean>
```

And voila! Each `item` returns as JSON String.

Comment: Sorry, your question isn't clear to me right now. I've just shown in my answer how to configure it to deals with raw JSON. I see your simiar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117576/spring-batch-mongoitemreader-how-to-pass-jobparameters-to-mongo-query) for similar unfurled answer from Michael... Looks like a DDOS attack from your side...

Comment: @Artem - Could you guide on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530697/org-springframework-dao-dataaccessresourcefailureexception-unable-to-write-to-f?