# Spring Batch | MongoItemReader | How to pass JobParameters to mongo query?

Tags: spring-batch

How can I pass `JobParameters` to `MongoItemReader` query ?

My ItemReader looks like :-

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<Person> PersonTenantBasedItemReader() {
    MongoItemReader<Person> reader = new MongoItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    reader.setTargetType((Class<? extends Person>) Person.class);
    reader.setQuery("{status:'XYZ',nextCheckpointDate:{$gte:?fromDate,$lte:?toDate}"); // !!!!I want to pass fromDate and toDate as job parameters. !!!!    
    Map<String, Direction> sorts = new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>(1);
    sorts.put("status", Sort.Direction.ASC);
    reader.setSort(sorts);
    return reader;
}
```

This is how I am launching the Job:-

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Map<String, JobParameter> map = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>(2);
    map.put("fromDate", new JobParameter(new Date()));
    map.put("toDate", new JobParameter(//some future date comes here);
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(map);
    JobExecution run = launcher.run(job, jobParameters);
    Assert.assertNotNull(run);
}
```

I am getting this exception:-

```
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{status:'DELINQUENT',nextCheckpointDate:{$gte:?fromDate,$lte:?toDate}
                                              ^
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:216)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:249)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:213)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:249)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:213)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:163)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery.<init>(BasicQuery.java:39)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader.doPageRead(MongoItemReader.java:176)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.AbstractPaginatedDataItemReader.doRead(AbstractPaginatedDataItemReader.java:59)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:155)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:114)
```

Comment: as PersonTenantBasedItemReader() param binded with @Value("#{jobParameters[]}") annotation

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Can you please elaborate with some code/example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues I see with your configuration:

1. In order to inject `JobParameter` values, you need to use the Step scope.  Your bean is currently configured using the singleton scope (default).
2. You aren't actually injecting the parameters into your method.

Give the following a try:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MongoItemReader<Person> PersonTenantBasedItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[fromDate]}") String fromDate, @Value("#{jobParameters[toDate]}") String toDate) {
    MongoItemReader<Person> reader = new MongoItemReader<Person>();
    reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    reader.setTargetType((Class<? extends Person>) Person.class);
    reader.setQuery(String.format("{status:'XYZ',nextCheckpointDate:{ %s ? %s }", fromDate, toDate));
    Map<String, Direction> sorts = new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>(1);
    sorts.put("status", Sort.Direction.ASC);
    reader.setSort(sorts);
    return reader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Object> param = new ArrayList<Object>();
param.add(fromDate);
param.add(toDate)
reader.setQuery("{status:'XYZ',nextCheckpointDate:{$gte:?0,$lte:?1}");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.