# org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to write to file resource: [class path resource [report.xml]]; Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am developing `Spring Batch - MongoDB to XML` example. I have successfully developed the code, when I run the my main program. I see the following eror comes. I am not sure what is going wrong. I followed many links, but I dont see its not working fine.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to write to file resource: [class path resource [report.xml]]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [report.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter.open(StaxEventItemWriter.java:436) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter.open(StaxEventItemWriter.java:400) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:21) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [report.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:48) ~[spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter.open(StaxEventItemWriter.java:427) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
13:21:05.358 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
13:21:05.367 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
13:21:05.368 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@5b202a3a]
13:21:05.368 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
13:21:05.375 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
13:21:05.375 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@5669c5fb]
13:21:05.379 [main] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Exception while closing step execution resources in step step1 in job reportJob
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter.close(StaxEventItemWriter.java:659) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.close(CompositeItemStream.java:85) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.close(TaskletStep.java:305) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:271) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:134) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:21) [classes/:na]
13:21:05.381 [main] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Step execution complete: StepExecution: id=1, version=2, name=step1, status=FAILED, exitStatus=FAILED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=0
13:21:05.381 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.updateExecutionContext]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
13:21:05.383 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
13:21:05.383 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@178213b]
13:21:05.383 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Completed state=reportJob.step1 with status=FAILED
13:21:05.385 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Handling state=reportJob.fail0
13:21:05.385 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.c.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow - Completed state=reportJob.fail0 with status=FAILED
13:21:05.388 [main] DEBUG o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Job execution complete: JobExecution: id=0, version=1, startTime=Sun Jan 08 13:21:05 IST 2017, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Sun Jan 08 13:21:05 IST 2017, status=FAILED, exitStatus=exitCode=FAILED;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=0, version=0, Job=[reportJob]], jobParameters=[{}]
13:21:05.388 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
13:21:05.397 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
13:21:05.397 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.s.t.ResourcelessTransactionManager - Committing resourceless transaction on [org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager$ResourcelessTransaction@2d36e77e]
13:21:05.397 [main] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [FlowJob: [name=reportJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [FAILED]
Exit Status : FAILED
Done
```

**job-report.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch  http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

       <!-- connect to mongodb -->
    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="yourdb" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>

    <batch:job id="reportJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="mongodbItemReader" writer="xmlItemWriter" commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="mongodbItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader">
        <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
        <property name="collection" value="report" />
        <property name="targetType" value="com.mkyong.Report" />
        <property name="query" value="" />
        <property name="sort">
            <util:map id="sort">
                <entry key="id" value="" />
            </util:map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="xmlItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
        <!-- <property name="resource" value="classpath:xml/report.xml" /> -->
        <property name="resource" value="report.xml" />
        <property name="marshaller" ref="reportMarshaller" />
        <property name="rootTagName" value="record" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ==== Solution-1 ==== -->
    <bean id="reportMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <value>com.mkyong.Report</value>
        </property>
   </bean> 

    <!-- ==== Solution-2 ==== -->
    <!-- <bean id="reportMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
        <property name="aliases">
            <util:map id="aliases">
                <entry key="record" value="com.mkyong.Report" />
            </util:map>
        </property>
        <property name="converters">
            <array>
                <ref bean="reportConverter" />
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean> -->

    <bean id="reportConverter" class="com.mkyong.ReportConverter" />
</beans>
```

**Report.java**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "record")
public class Report {

    private int id;
    private Date date;
    private long impression;
    private int clicks;
    private BigDecimal earning;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "date")
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "impression")
    public long getImpression() {
        return impression;
    }

    public void setImpression(long impression) {
        this.impression = impression;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "clicks")
    public int getClicks() {
        return clicks;
    }

    public void setClicks(int clicks) {
        this.clicks = clicks;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "earning")
    public BigDecimal getEarning() {
        return earning;
    }

    public void setEarning(BigDecimal earning) {
        this.earning = earning;
    }
}
```

**App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] springConfig = { "database.xml", "context.xml", "job-report.xml" };

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);

        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
        Job job = (Job) context.getBean("reportJob");

        try {
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Looking forward to get the response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the resource value for xmlItemWriter is incorrect.  You can provide a classpath or file/URL.

See "Table 8.1. Resource strings" at this link http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resourceloader